# Issue while running ant command

Tags: java, ant

I installed ant in my system, when I run `ant` command, I get following error:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.   We cannot execute
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/bin/java

Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: probably set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the Java executable on your system correctly.  Guessing what might be wrong: Should the path to your Java executable have a repeated `/bin` in it?

Comment: Have have to set JAVA_HOME correctly. It must be only `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/`

Comment: My JAVA version is 1.7.0_67

Comment: You are getting /bin/bin/java which is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the installation directory of your JDK, which is: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`

It looks like you have set it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin` (note the `/bin` at the end); the `ant` command appends another `/bin` so that you get `.../bin/bin/java` which is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

In your Java installation directory, u can see a jre subdirectory that contains the bin directory that contains java and related executables.

So you should probably be setting JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/jre rather than /usr/lib/jvm/jdk.

Comment: may i know whats wrong in that answer to downvote it?

Comment: Any link from sun or authenticated source which suggests setting java home your way.

Comment: I have just posted my view to rechek the path set by referring to some posts.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is always java home and not JRE home.